# C# KeyPress Event doesn't copy last character from text box to form's text property

Tags: c#, string, copy, keypress

Situation: 
A form has a text box in which the user must type some text. This text box has a KeyPress event in which the Form's text property changes to the text that the user types with each keystroke.

Here's the code for the textbox's KeyPress Event:

```
 private void tbGameTitle_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Problem:
The last character the user types doesn't get copied to the Form's text. Example:

```
textBox1.Text = "The War of 1812"
Form2.Text = "The War of 181"
```

The "2" at the end of "The War of 1812" in textBox1.Text doesn't get copied to Form2.Text.

How can I get the whole text string to copy from textBox1.Text to Form2.Text?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event instead of `KeyPress`. You're a fraction too early when using the latter, since the `Text` property gets updated after the key press has been handled.

Answer (score 2):

That is because [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) gets fired before the character actually "enters" `textBox1`.  If you watch as you type, you'll notice that `Form2` will always be a character behind `textBox1`.  You'll want to use the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event instead, which gets fired *after* each change to the text in `textBox1`.

Comment: The KeyUp event would also be appropriate here, as this event fires after the key has been pressed and then released.

Comment: Correct, although that event handles non-character keys that don't change the text of `textBox1`, which we don't care about.  `TextChanged` would catch only the relevant key presses.

Comment: agreed, things like up arrow, down arrow, delete, enter, etc.

Comment: Yes, although "delete" may change the text, so we do care about that one (it would be caught by `TextChanged` as well though).

Comment: yes, but if the carat is at the end of the string, then there would be no effect when using the delete key, alternately, if the carat was at the start of the string, and the backspace key was used, again no text change,